# QBSDK linking invoice to estimate

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am using the QBSDK QBFC12Lib in C#.Net with Reckon Accounts 2013 (Quickbooks Australia/NZ version).  It is a test version but has been activated.

I have the basics working.  I can add a customer, job, estimate and invoice and run queries against them.

But I can't link an invoice to an estimate (to keep track of progress invoicing).  If I try to add the estimate TxnID as a `LinkToTxnID`, when I submit the request I get the error message 3210 - `Object "25-1376628895" specified in the request cannot be found`.

I have verified that `EstimateID` is providing the correct TxnID for the estimate (25-1376628895).  It was selected by querying the estimate anyway and if I add an invoice to the estimate manually using Quickbooks itself and then query that invoice using the SDK it gives me the same TxnID under linked transactions.

These are the relevant lines of code:

```
IInvoiceAdd invoiceAdd = requestMsgSet.AppendInvoiceAddRq();

invoiceAdd.LinkToTxnIDList.Add(EstimateID);
```

Is it possible to link an invoice to an estimate using the SDK?  And if so, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i am getting Error with the QBFC12 with Reckon accounting 2013 in windows 7. error is "Could not start QuickBooks." do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is supported in the SDK. The programmer's guide only gives information on how to link an invoice to a sales order. Since the LinkToTxnIDList does not give an option for what type of transaction type it is, I would guess that it is only looking for SalesOrders when supplying the ID. I also tested linking by specifying the individual line item ID and still get the same error.

Perhaps as a workaround, you could create a SalesOrder from the Estimate (assuming that you can link them), and then create an invoice from the SalesOrder.

Comment: That is a good idea.  I will try using a Sales Order tonight.  My other alternative is to maintain the estimate outside of Quickbooks.  I can use my software to control the the 'percent complete' component - it is really only the invoice itself that has to be in Quickbooks (for sales tax and P&L).  And since I understand it isn't possible to print invoices using the SDK I am going to have to create my own progress invoices anyway.

Comment: Sales Order doesn't quite do what I want - when you link to a Sales Order on an invoice you don't get the % columns we want for progress claims (Prior %, Current %, Total %).  But I think you are right that the SDK doesn't support linking of invoices to estimates.  That would explain why it can't find a valid TxnID.  I have marked this as the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i am getting Error with the QBFC12 with Reckon accounting 2013 in windows 7. error is "Could not start QuickBooks." do you have any idea ?